# Is this understanding of cross validation good?

Tags: cross-validation

I have fitted my model, checked the diagnostics, and it looks good.

From wiki, I now understand that "cross validation" can be used to check the predictive accuracy of my model.

How exactly does this work in practice?

Say my original data is 1000 data lines. So I split it into 5 groups. Then I fit a model on each group, and test it on the other 800 data lines.

So, far, so good. Then what? Every time I test it, what "statistic" do I compute? And after I do that 5 times, do I average that statistic? Or, do I do something else to measure the accuracy?

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the "wiki" you reference in your post to add some context for others.

Comment: You'd generally want to fit the model on 800 data lines, and test on the remaining 200 lines. Thus, the constructed models do a have a significant amount of overlap between them, but because they have more training points, they are more representative of actual performance.

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly does this work in practice?
>   Say my original data is 1000 data lines. So I split it into 5 groups. Then I fit a model on each group, and test it on the other 800 data lines.

Yes. In practice, you need to make sure that you split your data well: the splits need to be independent of each other and they usually should be representative for the whole data set.

In particular, if you have structure in your data (e.g. data sorted wrt. the independent variable or clusters of rows that may be more similar to each other) you need to take that into account in your splitting.

> So, far, so good. Then what? Every time I test it, what "statistic" do I compute?

This depends on your application. Cross validation is just a plan how to get test cases. What figure of merit (statistic) you calculate is independent of how exactly you get your test cases.

One possible statistic would be accuracy for classification. For regression, root mean squared error RMSE is a frequent choice. Brier's score would be a mean squared error for classification.

> And after I do that 5 times, do I average that statistic? Or, do I do something else to measure the accuracy?

Often, not the statistic but the test predictions are pooled: the underlying assumption of cross validation is that each of your 5 so-called surrogate models is (approximately) equal to "the model" trained using all cases. Therefore, you use the test predictions of the surrogate models as surrogate for test predictions of "the model".

Whether or not pooling predictions is the same as averaging the statistic dependy on the figure of merit you look at (and on whether your splits have exactly the same size). E.g. the mean of 5 RMSE's is typically not the same as the RMSE of all predictions of the 5 surrogate models.

Answer (score 1):

I find that the broad use of the term "model" to mean "the model type" in some contexts, and "the specific instantiation of a particular model type" in other contexts to be partly responsible for a lot of confusion when one discusses topics like this.

A model *type* is a particular functional form which we believe fits our data best. E.g. it may be a linear model, quadratic, gaussian, etc. These models have a general form which relies on parameters; when we talk about a *specific* instance of a particular model type (or a "model instance"), we mean a model of that type for a *specific* set of parameters. *However*, some model *types* can be expressed as a *family* of model types, and the choice of a particular model type from that family is often selected by using what's called *hyperparameters*.

A good example of this are polynomial models. E.g. if you're trying to model the probability of a variable $x$ using a polynomial model, then your model has functional form $y(x ; \mathbf{w}) = w_0 + w_1x + w_2x^2 + \dots + w_Mx^M$.

There are two things to note here. This is not a *single* model. It represents a *family* of polynomial models. So, for $M=1$ the model type is specifically a polynomial of degree 1, for $M=2$ it is a specific model type of polynomial of degree 2, etc.

Then, once you choose your *actual* explicit model type, you can try to perform optimisation for that model type, by optimising its parameters $\mathbf{w}$.

If you repeat your experiment for different values of $M$, you are effectively trying to choose the model *type* (albeit still restricting yourself to the family of polynomial models) which has the potential to fit your data best. For each experiment (i.e. a given model type, i.e. a specific value for $M$), your objective is to find the most optimal set of parameters $\mathbf{w}$ for that model type.

If you had partitioned your dataset into a training set and a validation set, and you were to then assess the accuracy of your optimal model *instance* (i.e. the optimal solution for $\mathbf{w}$) on those two sets at each M, you would probably get something like this:

[image]

which indicates that for models that are *too* simple (i.e. choice for $M$ is too low, e.g. a straight line can't approximate a curve too well) the model undeperforms (has a high error), but for models that are too *complicated* (i.e. choice for $M$ is too high) the model overfits the data because it is more susceptible to noisy data.

So what's the role of *cross*-validation then? Well, if you partition your dataset (i.e. split it into training and validation sets) one way, you get one value for training set accuracy, and one validation set accuracy at each M. But if you try a *number* of *different* partitions, then you can get *many* values for training set and validation set accuracy at each M. In other words, you can now also talk about the distribution of the accuracy in the training and validation sets at each M.

You can imagine however, that this comes at the cost of having to run more experiments, to obtain that kind of information. Specifically, if you try N random partitions for each M, you will have to perform $N\times M$ experiments.

A structured way of performing cross validation is to divide a dataset into N partitions, and to use one of those for validation, and the remaining $N-1$ partitions as the training set. If you choose a different partition for the validation set each time, you effectively have N experiments you can run. But in reality, this is just a conventional way of doing it, and in reality your partitioning scheme could be arbitrary.

So in summary, cross-validation is a method to get a better idea how optimal solution accuracy is *distributed* for a particular model *type*, and e.g. talk about the model type's accuracy *on average* (rather than, say, rely on a single accuracy measurement, which may represent an outlier). And more generally, it is considered to be a method of making a more informed choice for the hyperparameters of a model type, or in terms of selecting between model types in general.

Compare and contrast this to *bootstrapping* where you say, I will obtain a number of *samples* (nothing to do with partitions) from my dataset by sampling with or without repetition, and find the optimal $\mathbf{w}$ for each of those samples. I.e. this attempts to build a distribution over the optimal $\mathbf{w}$ solutions. But this still represents a single experiment, and the outcome of that experiment may be, for instance, that you pick the mode of that $\mathbf{w}$ distribution as the most representative optimal solution for that experiment. Which you would then validate to assess its accuracy. If you were to perform cross validation in that context, then you'd essentially partition your dataset first, and then bootstrap over your training partition each time to obtain bootstrapped samples.

Read Bishop, Pattern Matching and Machine Learning Chapter 1 for more details

Answer (score 0):

In general, Available data is split into three parts: *training*, *cross validation*, and *testing*. One would use *training* for fitting the model, then use *cross validation* data to analyse and select the right meta characteristics of the model. Finally, *test data* is used **only** for finding the accuracy of the generated model.

For example, suppose you have two linear regression models trained by a given *training data*, one being quadratic and the other being cubic (the model being quadratic or cubic is the meta data here), you can then use the *cross validation* data to compare which model has generalized better. Suppose you have decided that the quadratic model is the better model, then use *test data* to find the accuracy of the model.

The split is usually 60-20-20 or 50-25-25.

Comment: You can totally use cv to assess the accuracy of the model. Generally, if you do not have any meta character that are fit via CV, CV works perfectly well.

Comment: While this answer isn't wrong it doesn't answer the question and thereby may confuse OP even further.  In addition as Josh already commented, this looks as if you did not understand cross validation very well yourself.